# NodeJS, express and mongoDB - mapping logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile, pug, express

**Nothing important in this paragraph** - I am still new to programming and getting the hang of nodejs, so for this question I am only asking for someone to explain the logical process I should take. I can figure it out from there and I feel as though this would be a great example for beginners like myself so I will post the code for the final solution.

**The Situation**
-I have one mongo database containing customers(there are 100's of customers. It has 3 fields (First, Last, Age)
-The Customers receive a monthly service. Everyday the company assigns to each of their small number of employees a random list of these customers to take care of.
-I have already created a second Schema in the mongo database that has four fields; the employee assigned to the daily list, the date, an array filled with the ID fields of many customers, and a Boolean value (employee, date, array, boolean) - {i need the second schema for archive purposes}

**The problem -**
 I need to query the employee list (2nd) database for incomplete lists( aka false boolean values); Then create, show or active a link to a view for each of the incomplete lists, the individual views will be populated by querying the customer database(1st database) by the arguement of the ID fields that I retrieve from the array in the 2nd database. And I need to create that link and populate the view for each of incomplete lists. I am using NodeJS, Express and Jade, but like i said in the paragraph you skipped if you could just map out the logic I can get started and will post my final result.

Thank You for any attempts. It is now almost 9pmEST, I will be monitoring my post until atleast 11pmEST if anyone needs any clarification. and again tomorrow morning
-Steven R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having what I understand, is that they have 2 databases. Parese to me a little more simple to do. Use ObjectId with a field "boolesean" or numeric, this field should modify or change the connection to the database. So solve the problem of having multiple databases and you can relate. If you use ObjectId, you can do research in other collections and in this case in other databases. use [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) That will help you build better databases, and search on different levels.

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts please.